# How do I take the file I receive instead of taking it from my computer?

Tags: java, json, xml

```
   @Autowired
   private ContrattoDao contrattoDao;

   @Autowired
   private FileContrattoDao fileContrattoDao;

   protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContrattoController.class);

   private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody JsonResponse _sendData(@RequestBody String stringContratto) {

         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         JsonResponse jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
         FileContratto fileContratto = new FileContratto();
         Contratto jsonContratto = new Contratto();

         try{   

                JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(stringContratto);
           String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
           System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);

                fileContratto.setFileContratto(jsonPrettyPrintString);                    
                fileContrattoDao.save(fileContratto);

                jsonContratto = mapper.readValue(jsonPrettyPrintString, Contratto.class);
                contrattoDao.save(jsonContratto);

                jsonResponse.addReturnCode(ResultMapping.SUCCESS.getResultCode());
                jsonResponse.addErrorMsg(ResultMapping.SUCCESS.getErrorMessage());

         }catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                jsonResponse.addReturnCode(ResultMapping.INTERNAL_ERROR.getResultCode());
                jsonResponse.addErrorMsg(ResultMapping.INTERNAL_ERROR.getErrorMessage());
         }
         return jsonResponse;
   }
```

This is my code. 
The situation is: I am receiving a file from an external client, which we know it's an HTML.
"stringContratto" contains the file I'm receiving.

How do I do put the file I receive in a new doc I can use and analyze there in the code?
I tried to parse it into JSON, but that's pretty much useless.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad. How do you "analyze" the doc? What stopping you from analyzing it right there in `String` form? Why did you try to parse it as JSON if you knew it would be HTML?

Comment: In general, this sounds like Jaxb deserialization. What you will need is JAXB `Unmarshaller` and some concrete class that you will unmarshall your data into. You will also need to define some data schema so your unmarshaller will understand the data flow. And I guess you will want customized `ValidationEventHandler` to cope with mess in your inputs and decide which input mess warrants a proper exception and which is to be ignored.